# Twilio - Voice - Javascript SDK - Issue in Incoming call - Capture call disconnect

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have setup a webhook for incoming call which forwards the call to a browser javascript client.

The browser client, on incoming call, asks the user to accept or reject the call. The call is continued or rejected based on the user's choice.

The issue is when the call is waiting at the browser client and the user is not reacted yet, the call times out and the caller is forwarded to voice mail.

However, the browser client still waits for the user to respond. The user comes to know about the timeout after accepting the call.

I tried to use the call disconnect event but it is not invoked. Below is the JS code used. How to resolve this issue?

```
function disconnectCall() { 
    $("#m_callsubmit").show();  
    $("#endcall").hide();       
    $("#hangup").hide();  
    if(swal.isVisible()){swal.close();}         
}

async function startupClient() {
    try {const data = await $.getJSON("");token = data.token;intitializeDevice();} 
    catch (err) {console.log(err);}
}
  

function intitializeDevice() {
    device = new Twilio.Device(token, {logLevel: 1,codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"]});

    device.on("registered", function () { $("#spnDeviceR").show();  $("#spnDeviceN").hide(); }); 

    device.on("error", function (error) { $("#spnDeviceR").hide(); $("#spnDeviceN").show(); $("#spnDeviceN").attr("title", error.message);  cosole.log(error.message); });

    device.on("incoming", function (call) {  

    call.on("disconnect", disconnectCall);  

    swal.fire({
    text: "You have a Call.",
    type: "info",showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Accept",cancelButtonText: "Reject",}).then(function(result){
    if (result.value) { call.accept(); scallid = call.parameters.CallSid ;  $("#m_callsubmit").hide();  $("#endcall").show();       $("#hangup").show();    }
    else if (result.dismiss === "cancel") { call.reject();   } })   }); 

    device.register();
}

startupClient();
```